# ggplot: x-axis in linear scale

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am generating a graph by taking log of the values like this:

```
## Example
x <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(100),v2=rnorm(100,1,1),v3=rnorm(100,0,2))
library(ggplot2);library(reshape2)
ex<- melt(x)
p1 = ggplot(ex,aes(x=log(value,2),color=variable))
p1 + geom_freqpoly(alpha=0.25)
```

But need to show linear values on x-axis rather then log2 ones. Could you suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the labels with `scale_x_continuous`.  Here, the breaks are extracted from the plot and relabeled.

```
## Construct graph as you have done
p1 <- ggplot(ex, aes(x=log(value,2), color=variable)) +
  geom_freqpoly(alpha=0.5, lwd=1.1)

## Get the breaks
bs <- ggplot_build(p1)[[2]]$ranges[[1]]$x.major_source

## add new labels
p1 + scale_x_continuous(breaks=bs, labels=round(2**bs, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: nongkrong: Thanks for replying. Tried you approach but it gives error:      bs <- ggplot_build(p1)[[2]]$ranges[[1]]$x.major_source
Error: No layers in plot

Comment: @Bade you need to make assign to `p1` first, see edit